# Datanucleus RDBMS JPA jar-with-dependencues

Tags: java, jpa, datanucleus

I configured and I use Datanucleus JPA to connect to MySQL. I compile the classes and enhanced entities with datanucleus-enhancer-plugin. I can run my app using mvn exec:java and I can also run it after I create an archive with lib (jar dependencies).

The problem appears when I create a jar (jar-with-dependencies). I get this error:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Explicit persistence provider error(s) occurred for "mysql" after trying the following discovered implementations: org.datanucleus.api.jpa.PersistenceProviderImpl from provider: org.datanucleus.api.jpa.PersistenceProviderImpl
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createPersistenceException(Persistence.java:244)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:186)
    at cantina.crawler.util.JpaUtil.getRdbmsEntityManager(JpaUtil.java:29)
    at cantina.crawler.bolt.SiteDetectorBolt.prepare(SiteDetectorBolt.java:32)
    at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__4050$fn__4059.invoke(executor.clj:610)
    at backtype.storm.util$async_loop$fn__465.invoke(util.clj:375)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusException: Error creating handler of type "persistence" for metadata parsing : MetaData handler plugin "persistence" was not found. Please check your CLASSPATH and plugin specification.
    at org.datanucleus.metadata.xml.MetaDataParser.parseMetaDataStream(MetaDataParser.java:269)
    at org.datanucleus.metadata.xml.MetaDataParser.parseMetaDataURL(MetaDataParser.java:137)
    at org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataUtils.parsePersistenceFiles(MetaDataUtils.java:956)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.JPAEntityManagerFactory.<init>(JPAEntityManagerFactory.java:342)
at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.PersistenceProviderImpl.createEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProviderImpl.java:91)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:152)
... 6 more
Caused by: org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusUserException: MetaData handler plugin "persistence" was not found. Please check your CLASSPATH and plugin specification.
    at org.datanucleus.metadata.xml.MetaDataParser.parseMetaDataStream(MetaDataParser.java:263)
... 11 more
```

I unziped the jar and the datanucleus-core files are there. I can not figure out what is happening.

Comment: could you find a solution in the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've not bothered looking after MANIFEST.MF and plugin.xml files when you changed the jar(s). DataNucleus jars are packaged to allow the (OSGi-based) plugin mechanism to identify plugins and capabilities. You've disabled that by playing around with those jars, so get the consequences.

Solution : either use the jars as provided, or merge them correctly (in which case it's your responsibility)

Comment: Hey, I am getting the same error here. I downloaded the [Access Platform](http://www.datanucleus.org/download.html) ZIP file, then put all the JARs in `lib` and `deps` into my CLASSPATH. Am I missing something?